# What is the difference between a Java test project with selenium and Java Maven test project with selenium as well

Tags: java, maven, testing, selenium, junit

I generally use "Java project" to import Selenium test cases. What if i wanted to use Maven ? Should I create the project at the beginning as "Maven project"? What is the difference between to of them these both should provide the tester same test steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there would be no difference in your test steps.

Maven is a way to build your java project and is excellent for handling dependencies.

So you would create it as a "Maven Project" and add Selenium as a dependency.

This shows you how to add Selenium dependency to Maven-
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

Comment: As i could research which is too important;
newbies like me if they created a java project and if they realized that it should be a maven project, they can make like project->configure->convert to maven project. And then they can add the selenium stuff in the pom.xml as specified above. Thanks !